# No sound after installing 11.10

Tags: 11.10

After installing the update to 11.10 the sound on my computer is gone. What happened? I have a HDA Intel with a Realtek ALC1200 chipset. Is there a simple solution to this problem. I'm no computernerd.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information?

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities:

1. You login to gnome as root. The pulseaudio daemon is not getting started when you login as root into gnome. On console, try:

   open /usr/bin/pulseaudio
2. You got a new kernel (not surprising, considering you updated to a new Ubuntu version). This means you should now recompile the ALSA (advanced Linux sound architecture) driver (the Ubuntu team always forgets this, for whatever reason). Afterwards, sound works fine (until the next kernel-upgrade)

   cat /proc/asound/version

http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Main_Page

Mine shows

> Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version 1.0.24.